# Show custom field on module featured product opencart

Tags: controller, opencart

I need show this custom field on Module Featured product

[image: Check image here]

Currently it only shows this field on the product page,
Need to show this field in module Featured product

I already put this code in the Controller
catalog/controller/extension/module/featured.php
    $data['extra_field'] = html_entity_decode($product_info['extra_field'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

But no work...
Can someone help me?

This is custom field

```
<modification>
<name><![CDATA[<font color="#000000"><b>sale</font>]]></name>
<code>product_extra_field</code>
<version>1.0</version>

<link></link>

<file path="admin/controller/catalog/product.php">
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[if (isset($this->request->post['points'])) {]]></search>
        <add position="before"><![CDATA[if ($this->db->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '". DB_PREFIX ."product_extra_field'")->num_rows == 0) {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_extra_field` (
              `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
              `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
              `extra_field`VARCHAR(125) NOT NULL
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM COLLATE=utf8_general_ci";
        $this->db->query($sql);          
  }
                if (isset($this->request->post['product_extra_field'])) {
        $data['product_extra_field'] = $this->request->post['product_extra_field'];
    } elseif (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
        $data['product_extra_field'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductExtraField($this->request->get['product_id']);
    } else {
        $data['product_extra_field'] = array();
    }]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>

<file path="admin/model/catalog/product.php">
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[foreach ($data['product_description'] as $language_id => $value) {]]></search>
        <add position="before"><![CDATA[$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_extra_field WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
        foreach ($data['product_extra_field'] as $language_id => $value) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_extra_field SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', extra_field = '" . $this->db->escape($value['extra_field']) . "'");
        }]]></add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[public function getProductOptions($product_id) {]]></search>
        <add position="before"><![CDATA[public function getProductExtraField($product_id) {
                $product_extra_field_data = array();

                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_extra_field WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

                foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
                    $product_extra_field_data[$result['language_id']] = array(
                        'extra_field'             => $result['extra_field']
                    );
                }

                return $product_extra_field_data;
            }]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>

<file path="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search index="0"><![CDATA[<div class="form-group">]]></search>
        <add position="before"><![CDATA[<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-extra_field<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>">Texto personalizado</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <textarea class="form-control" name="product_extra_field[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][extra_field]" placeholder="Digite aqui" id="input-extra_field<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo isset($product_extra_field[$language['language_id']]) ? $product_extra_field[$language['language_id']]['extra_field'] : ''; ?></textarea>
                </div>
             </div>]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>






<file path="catalog/controller/product/product.php">
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[$data['points'] = $product_info['points'];]]></search>
        <add position="before"><![CDATA[$data['extra_field'] = html_entity_decode($product_info['extra_field'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>

<file path="catalog/model/catalog/product.php">
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[return array(]]></search>
        <add position="before"><![CDATA[
            $extra_field_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_extra_field WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");
            if($extra_field_query->num_rows)  {
                $extra_field = $extra_field_query->row['extra_field'];
            } else {
                $extra_field = "";
            }]]></add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[return array(]]></search>
        <add position="after">
            <![CDATA[
            'extra_field'       => $extra_field,]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>

<file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/product.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[<?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>]]></search>
        <add position="after"><![CDATA[<?php if(isset($extra_field) && $extra_field) { ?>
            <?php echo $extra_field; ?>
            <?php } ?>]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get your code working in featured products, too; which uses a different codebase than product.php:

Controller:
/**your_dir**/catalog/controller/extension/module/featured.php:

Around:

```
'name'        => $product_info['name'],
'extra_field' => $product_info['extra_field'],
```

View:
/**your_dir**/catalog/view/theme/**your_theme**/template/extension/module/featured.tpl:
Add it where you want it to show, like:

```
<?php if ($product['extra_field']) { ?>
     //your extra field stuff goes here
<?php } ?>
```